# how to mount extended partition in ubuntu for all users

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

sir,
I am a new user of Ubuntu 12.04. I faced a problem, my Ubuntu 12.04 has two user one is administrator and another is sudo user. I have 3 partition one Ubuntu file system and rest two partition is NTFS partition.
When i mount these partition as a administrator then the sudo user can't see those partitions, if i mount these partition as a sudo user then the administrator can't see those partitions.
Please help me and guide to solve this problem.[image: my HDD partition picture]

Comment: sudo is superuser and should be able to browse and see any folder. What method are you using to mount them and what do you want to do with them using superuser rights?

Comment: "one is administrator and another is sudo user": is not clear. Any `sudo`-user is an administrator of the system.

Comment: But sudo user can't see any extended partition in his user account. So please tell me how to automount on startup.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to make an [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) entry for the drive(s)

Then create a new group, add the users to the group, and then recursively modify permissions on the drive to according to your needs.